# Update Fragment A after the flow A > B > C > D is successfull

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, notifications, onactivityresult

I have Fragment A under a PageViewer, there is a button that starts the flow B > C > D (all of these are activities).

After D is successful (and only if it is successful) I want to update fragment A. ¿Which is the best way to do this?

- Use onActivityResult all the way back?
- Use sharedPreferences to determine the update when fragment A is visible
- Use static variable in A
- Create static model M that manages listeners and notification-like messages, so that A is registered and D send the message via M.

Also, there will be another fragment E, that can also call the flow B > C > D and will update E when successful

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is by using passing arguments to the fragment via `

```
// Supply index input as an argument. 
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("index", index);
f.setArguments(args);
```

Every time D becomes visible, you can change some value in the arguments to indicate that an update has to be made. When A comes back into view, it can read the argument and then update itself.

You can do this in the `onPageSelected` of the `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`.

Essentially the same as `SharedPreference`, really. :-/